# Could not launch Appium Inspector - iOS

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium for UI Automation testing for iOS application. I am trying to use Inspector from Appium tool through prelanuch simulator option. Whenever I click on "Inspector", I am getting error as shown in below screenshot.

I am doing anything wrong here?
[image: error message]

Here are the settings that I have done,

[image: settings]

[image]

Comment: Could you share the 500 error logs from appium server for the same instance.

Comment: Also please make sure you have `Use Native Instruments Library` checked under `Advance settings` for IOS platform in Appium's UI and `Enable UI Automation` setting in setting--developer in your device.

Comment: Have you started the appium server ?